# SPRING4: Failed to read candidate component class CouchbaseConfig.class

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-couchbase

I have a problem. I'm using Spring4 and i want to add a configuration to be able to use spring data couchbase and i have an error :

> *org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file
>   [/home/charlie/Desktop/Ultimate
>   Projects/novare_dashboard/novare-project-dashboard/target/classes/hk/com/novare/dashboard/configuration/CouchbaseConfig.class];
>   nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError:
>   Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class
>   org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.EnableCouchbaseRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:303)*

Here is my code:

**CouchbaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration{

@Override
protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
    return Collections.singletonList("localhost");
}

@Override
protected String getBucketName() {
    return "crud";
}

@Override
protected String getBucketPassword() {
    return "password";
}}
```

**WebMvcConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = Application.class)
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/static/");
}}
```

**POM.XML**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!--H2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!--couchbase-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-couchbase</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.couchbase.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>couchbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--JSON-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: I have got the same problem, did you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Can see the error for missing repositoryBaseClass config which is needed to create the repository proxies for your CouchbaseConfig class :-

```
nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class 
org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.EnableCouchbaseRepositories.repositoryBaseClass() at
```

Pls specify same as parameter to @EnableCouchbaseRepositories

Comment: I also tried it before basePackages and baseClassesPackage   but still the same .

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [/home/charlie/Desktop/Ultimate Projects/novare_dashboard/novare-project-dashboard/target/classes/hk/com/novare/dashboard/configuration/CouchbaseConfig.class]; nested exception is java.lang.annotation.AnnotationFormatError: Invalid default: public abstract java.lang.Class org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.config.EnableCouchbaseRepositories.repositoryBaseClass()
*I also add  parameter but still the same
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories(basePackages = "hk.com.novare.dashboard")

Comment: Have you defined any interface with @Repository within that package which extends CouchbaseConfig ??

Comment: @Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {
}

**Here is my PersonRepository Class. I import this: -> 
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

Comment: It seems the issue is something else which is ending up showing these trails. Is your couchbase DB up & running while you were testing !!! Also i see you have h2 library in your pom, can you clean it as well and check.

Comment: I have h2 library  in POM as shown above. Yap couchbase db is running in my local

Comment: Could be some library version mismatch as well. Can you try changing the couchbase client version from <version>1.4.9</version> to <version>1.4.7</version>

Comment: I got still the same error..  when i change the version of spring data couchbase to 1.2.2 the error changed to "Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is"  
Btw Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Use spring data couchbase  1.2.2 and remove the @Repository on your repository and it will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution regarding my error. You must change your spring-data-couchbase version to  1.2.2  and remove the annotation @Repository to your repository.